# Left Aligned Social Media Icons in Zurb

Tags: zurb-foundation, html-email

I'm using Zurb Foundation for Email 2 and having a difficult time getting social media icons to align left. I am looking for a solution that works in this environment.

If you use this code from the drip.html template, you will get five icons centered nicely on the page.

```
<row class="collapsed footer">
  <columns>
    <center>
      <menu>
        <item><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt=""></item>
        <item><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt=""></item>
        <item><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt=""></item>
        <item><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt=""></item>
        <item><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt=""></item>
      </menu>
    </center>
  </columns>
</row>
```

I understand that those two tags are not supported in many email clients. I'd like to add that once you run the build code with Zurb, the `<menu>` and `<item>` tags get swapped out automatically with tables.

If you remove the `<center>` tag, the icons spread across the width of the page.

```
<table class="menu" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%">
  <tbody><tr style="font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top">
    <td style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #000000; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word">
      <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%">
      <tbody><tr style="font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top">
        <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
        <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
        <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
        <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
      <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
      </tr></tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

I've tried experimenting with the code, but I can't get the icons to flush left and look great. If you replace this with a simple table, you get a similar effect because of all of the styles written for Zurb, so that becomes a unweildy fix.

I was wondering if there's a solution that works with Zurb Foundation I have just overlooked.

- https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/fqs9qcLe/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might be after. I dont use Zurb but can give you the HTML that can make it work.

```html
<table align="left" class="menu" style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;">
  <tbody><tr style="font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top">
    <td style="-moz-hyphens: auto; -webkit-hyphens: auto; Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; border-collapse: collapse !important; color: #000000; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; hyphens: auto; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top; word-wrap: break-word">
      <table style="border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%">
      <tbody><tr style="font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding: 0; text-align: center; vertical-align: top">
        <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
        <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
        <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
        <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
      <th class="menu-item float-center" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #000000; float: none; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 10px; padding-right: 10px; text-align: center"><a href="undefined" style="Margin: 0; Margin-bottom: 10px; color: #2199e8; font-family: 'Gotham SSm A', 'Gotham SSm B', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 300; line-height: 1.3; margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: left; text-decoration: none"><img src="http://placehold.it/25/663399" alt="" style="-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: none; clear: both; display: block; max-width: 100%; outline: none; text-decoration: none; width: auto"></a></th>
      </tr></tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

What i have done to your HTML is remove the width of 100% (it centered the table), added left align to the table and it worked like a charm. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be because the menu element seems to get a fixed width.
You can solve it with a class on the menu element.

```
<row class="collapse">
    <menu class="menu-width-auto">
        <item href="#"><img src="img-path/instagram.png"></item>
        <item href="#"><img src="img-path/facebook-f.png"></item>
        <item href="#"><img src="img-path/pinterest-p.png"></item>
        <item href="#"><img src="img-path/twitter.png"></item>
    </menu>
</row>
```

Then in your sass:

```
table {
  &.menu {
    &.menu-width-auto {
      width: auto;
    }
  }
}
```